# Posting data using AJAX while using knockout bindings

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, knockout.js

I am finding it difficult to send data to the controller through Ajax post since the object to be sent to the controller cannot be used within the ajax post because of the structure of my code.I am using knockout for data-binding the click event of the Update button.

This is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {  
 var provider = function () {
var self = this;
self.providerID = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.ProviderID);
self.firstName = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.FirstName);
self.lastName = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.LastName);
self.contactEmail = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.ContactEmail);
self.NPI = ko.observable(providerEditInfo.NPI);

self.updateProviderDetails = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Provider/UpdateProviderDetails/",
        type: "POST",
        data: { providerForUpdate }, -- Cant send this
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.url) {
                location.href = result.url;
            }
        }
    });
};

self.cancelEdits = function () {
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to Cancel?")) {
        window.location.href = "/Provider/ShowTheListOfProviders";
      }
   };
}; //End of Constructor.

var providerForUpdate = new provider();
ko.applyBindings(providerForUpdate);
 });
On the clck of Update Button,I am calling the 'updateProviderDetails' method.

HTML

  @model Greenway.Demo.DataAccess.Entity.Provider
<body>
<div class="container">
<h1 class="col-sm-offset-2">Edit Provider Details:</h1>
<br />
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="editProviderDetailsForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">First Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" placeholder="Enter the First Name" id="firstName" name="firstName" data-bind="value:firstName , event: { keypress: allowOnlyAlphabets }">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label labelfont">Last Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter the Last Name" id="lastName" name="lastName" data-bind="value:lastName ,event: { keypress: allowOnlyAlphabets }">
        </div>
    </div>

   <div class="form-group text-center">
        <button type="Submit" data-bind="click: updateProviderDetails" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        <button type="button" data-bind="click: cancelEdits" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
       var providerEditInfo = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../../App_Scripts/Shared/Functions.js"></script>
```

Could someone guide me on how I can send the data to the controller with this code structure.I can't put updateProviderDetails outside the constructor because otherwise, I can't bind it.

Comment: Well i think you could separate your ajax function from the knockout model and call it separately, then send the knockout object as the data in the POST.

Comment: I cant databind it to the the click event in that case.I am using using knockout binding for the click event.So,the function has to be inside the knockout modekl.

Comment: Is the `self` variable not accessable in the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ko.toJSON` to serialize your view model to json:

```
self.updateProviderDetails = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Provider/UpdateProviderDetails/",
        type: "POST",
        data: ko.toJSON(self),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        async: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.url) {
                location.href = result.url;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

This is also in the [Knockout Tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=loadingsaving)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yes,I can the JSON data that is being sent to the controller.But the parameters on the controller side are null.The model on the controller side does not have all the fields that the viewmodel does.Could that be an issue?

Comment: Please update your post to contain the function header